# Spring boot datasource lazy initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

**@Lazy** annotation not working on datasource configuration. This datasource autowired into prototype scoped bean, but datasource initialize on startup eager. In stack tracei see call from **TomcatServletWebServerFactory**.

```
@Configuration
@Lazy
public class MsSqlMppvConfig {
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.mppvdatasource")
public DataSourceProperties mppvDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@Lazy
@Qualifier("mppvdatasource")
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.mppvdatasource.hikari")
public DataSource mppvDataSource() {
    return mppvDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}


@Bean(name = "tm_mppvdatasource")
@Autowired
DataSourceTransactionManager tm(@Qualifier("mppvdatasource") DataSource datasource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
}}

 @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mppvdatasource")
    @Lazy
    DataSource mppvDs;
```

Maybe problem in @Qualifier annotation?

Comment: When you add the autowire annotation (wherever you use your class/bean) you also need to use the @lazy annotation, is required in both places

Comment: Hope this can help https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when importing `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`. Had to change it to just use `spring-jdbc`